# Conditional str_to_date() if format is of one type, else do nothing

Tags: mysql, date, str-to-date

I have a table with dates, some of which have this format `31-DEC-2010` while others have this format `2011-01-13`.

I am trying to get all them having the date format, using the `str_to_date()` function, but it fails since it can not convert 2011-01-13 (some of the dates are already in the correct format because I ran this command previously but then I added more data)

```
UPDATE `Table1` SET `date` = str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%M-%Y' );
```

Is there some way to run this command only on the rows that have this format?

Comment: of which TYPE is the column `date` ?

Comment: You can search for date in given type by regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think of changing the data type to `date` and store dates in mysql fomat that will make life simple.

Now if you do a str_to_date() with a date format and the input is not in the format then it will return null.

```
mysql> select str_to_date( '2011-01-13', '%d-%M-%Y' ) as date;
+------+
| date |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

So you can do the trick as

```
update 
`Table1` 
SET `date` = case when str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%M-%Y' ) is null then date 
else str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%M-%Y' ) end
```

UPDATE

This might fall into a warning as

```
mysql> select str_to_date( '2011-01-13', '%d-%M-%Y' );
+-----------------------------------------+
| str_to_date( '2011-01-13', '%d-%M-%Y' ) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| NULL                                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings ;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                         |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '2011-01-13' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So the other approach is to use `regex` for the update

```
update 
`Table1` 
SET `date` = str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%M-%Y' )
where `date` not REGEXP('^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$')
```

Comment: I get ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '2011-01-13' for function str_to_date .. why ?

Comment: I try to accept both your answer and @Aziz Shaikh .. I don't know if that is possible but I think both of you are correct

Answer (score 4):

First SELECT records which have incorrect date format and then UPDATE those:

```
UPDATE `Table1` t
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM `Table1`
  WHERE str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%M-%Y' ) IS NOT NULL
) t2
ON t.id = t2.id
SET t.`date` = str_to_date( t.`date`, '%d-%M-%Y' )
```

Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f01565/1

Using `str_to_date` in UPDATE statement gives error, following will not work:

```
UPDATE `Table1` 
SET `date` = 
  CASE WHEN str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%M-%Y' ) IS NOT NULL
       THEN str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%M-%Y' )
       ELSE `date`
  END
```

Comment: I get ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '2011-01-13' for function str_to_date .. why ?

Comment: @adrCoder Using `str_to_date` in UPDATE statement gives error. I have updated my answer with a working fiddle link to verify.

Comment: I try to accept both your answer and @Abhik Chakraborty .. I don't know if that is possible but I think both of you are correct

Comment: @adrCoder you cannot accept 2 answers. However you may choose any answer you like. No worries. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought.. maybe it would work if I write :

```
mysql> UPDATE `Table1` 
       SET `date` = str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%M-%Y' )
       WHERE date LIKE '%d-%M-%Y';
```

(I am running the command atm, the table is very big, but it should normally stop immediately if it wouldn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can perform this task is using `COALESCE` function. which gives you first not null value from the provided values. you can create your query as following.

```sql
UPDATE `Table1` SET `date` = COALESCE(str_to_date( `date`, '%d-%M-%Y'), `date`);
```

This will first try to convert date to given format. if the string is not in the `%d-%M-%Y` format it will produce null so it will automatically chose `date` as a value. if it is in the format it will take `str_to_date( date, '%d-%M-%Y')` as a value since it is first value and not null.